# Error uploading IOS app to the app store: You must define the app binary as a routing app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, app-store-connect

These are developing a simple app in React Native with Expo, I do not use Maps or geolocation. only the most basic permissions for the operation of an app.

But when I send my app to review, I get the following error message by email:[image]

I was looking in many forums, I uploaded the .geojson file on the App store page but still it keeps sending me the same error, this is the.geojson

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon",
 "coordinates": [
   [[[-117.5, 16.5], [-87.9, 16.5], [-87.9,32.8], [-117.5, 32.8], [-117.5,16.5]]]
  ]
}
```

Please I need help, I'm going to lose my hair from frustration hahaha

Comment: If your app does not provide navigation routing remove the .geojson file and ensure that you have not added the "Maps" capability in the Xcode project.

Comment: But if I did it with react native, how can I see if it was added the "Maps" capability?

Comment: It did not work I delete the geojson and send to revision and the same error appears

Comment: You should not have uploaded the GeoJson file in the first place; Some similar [problems](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649258) indicate that you may be stuck.  If you have never released this app it may be simpler just to change the bundle ID and create a new entry in AppStore Connect.  Make sure you don't upload a routing coverage file at any time.

Comment: It did not work, I have to delete the app but I will no longer be able to use the name and it gives me other types of errors,I will have to contact the apple team again and see if they can solve something

Comment: @EmmanuelGarciaMartinez Hey, I have the same problem. Did you solve it and how?